# How to use MockMvc and Mockito(?) to make my stub return status code 500 or 400?

Tags: java, mockito, spring-test, stub, mockmvc

I'm testing spring controller that sends requests to 3rd party API and I would also like to write a JUnit test that stubs / mocks the API sending back HTTP 500 and 400 responses to see how it handles error answers. Being new to spring and autotesting, it is tough for me to see what I have to do to stub these HTTP 500 responses.
Here is my class with positive test method.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-cloud-stub.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {...})
public class ControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BisTechnicalChecksClient client;
    
    @Test
    public void TestMethod() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader().forType(new TypeReference<List<ClientsByAddrWithStartDateResponse>>() {
        });
        ClientsByAddrWithStartDateRequest request =
                mapper.readValue(new File("request_controller.json"),
                        ClientsByAddrWithStartDateRequest.class);

        List<ClientsByAddrWithStartDateResponse> response = reader.readValue(new File(
                "response_controller.json"));

        when(client.getClientsByAddrWithStartDate(any(ClientsByAddrWithStartDateRequest.class)))
                .thenReturn(response);

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .post("get-clients-by-addr-with-start-date")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .header("param1", "value1")
                        .content(mapper
                                .writer()
                                .withDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                                .writeValueAsString(request)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is2xxSuccessful())
                .andReturn();

        String stringResponse = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        List<ClientsByAddrWithStartDateResponse> actualResponse = reader.readValue(stringResponse);

        List<ClientsByAddrWithStartDateResponse> expectResponse = reader.readValue(new File(
                "response_controller.json"));

        Assertions.assertThat(actualResponse).isEqualTo(expectResponse);
    }

}
```

I've been trying to find a way to return preset MockHttpServletResponse when stubbed method is called but to no avail so far.
What do I need to change for my stub to return 500 / 400 statuses and work properly?

Comment: When you try to mock the result of your call - what do you actually test? The request is done in the test, the result would be mocked - what's left that you actually test?

Comment: @cyberbrain, I want to see if my controller can handle 500 and 400 answers the way it should

Comment: ah OK, your question didn't point that out and you did not provide controller code:
your controller calls another endpoint and has to be able to handle error results properly. You showed a test that in the first view tests the call of your controller.

Comment: How does your controller actually handle errors? I would expect `org.springframework.web.client.HttpStatusCodeException` to be thrown if an http request fails.